# Spring error_page cannot load css

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project.
I'm using Spring Security with this config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/static/**", "/index").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/premium/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","PREMIUM")
                        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","PREMIUM","USER")
                )
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                    .permitAll();
    }
```

This is my structure for html pages.

```
\resources
    \static
        \css
            style.css

    \templates
        index.html
        error_page.html
        \premium
            premium.html
```

In all the html files I have css loaded this way:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

When I open each of the pages separately, the css is loaded and everything works properly.

The problem happens when a user with the role "USER" tries to access the premium.html. Spring shows an error_page with the 403 error code. But this error page is located at the premium.html URL. In other words, URL bar shows www.domain/premium.html but the contents of the page are the ones of the error page. So the assets are not loaded with this error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () http://domain/premium/css/style.css`

A tried using th:href but with no luck.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{css/style.css}">`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `"/static/css/**"`. As you've mentioned it's giving 403 meaning somewhere spring security is not allowing to access.

Comment: Try that and let me know.

Comment: Still the same. The problem is that the page is looking for the assets in /premium/css/style.css where they are obviously not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the page is looking for the assets in /premium/css/style.css where they are obviously not present

What you're missing is a single slash `/`.

Instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{css/style.css}">
```

...please do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">
```

As stated in [Thymeleaf's documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls):

> Relative URLs starting with `/` (eg: `/order/details`) will be automatically prefixed by the application context name.

That way your link will be relative to application context (`http://domain/`) and will point to proper folder.